# Nodal Analysis by Inspection

Tags: circuit-analysis

I have a mechanical system which I have converted to its electrical equivalent. I am analysing the circuit using Nodal Analysis by Inspection to obtain the node voltages. I would like to create the Y (admittance) matrix but I am confused as to which nodes I should pick. For the particular problem I am solving, I need to find the voltage across the capacitors 1/M1 and 1/M3. Any help on selecting the nodes would be greatly appreciated. [image]

Comment: Seems to me that using a circuit simulator would be the best option.

Comment: you need to solve the entire circuit, hence for all nodes

Comment: Topologically, a graph with 5 nodes (one set as the ground reference) and 11 edges, not counting \$f_0\$. There is a reason not to count it, as the Rank-Nullity Theorem and the eventual use of a Schur complement in solving this suggests keeping it isolated. The admittance matrix will be, I believe, an 11x11 (square) with the conductances along the diagonal and elsewhere 0. That's the general situation. If you are only interested in two nodes, you likely can find by inspection of the resulting \$A^TCA\hat{x}=\hat{f}\$ how to reduce the work. Try Math.SE. They eat this stuff for breakfast.

Comment: To be clearer, say the column space and left null space of A is Ohm's Law (fluxes/currents are \$\left\{\hat{w}=A\hat{x}\right\}\text{ and }\left\{\hat{w}\vert \hat{w}^T A=\hat{0}\right\}\$) and that the row space of A and its (right) null space is KCL (\$\left\{\hat{x}=A^T\hat{w}\right\}\text{ and }\left\{\hat{x}\vert A\hat{x}=\hat{0}\right\}\$.)